# Date type column retirement day it should be null if more then 80 years

Tags: apache-spark-sql

Date difference between current date and some dates if it's more than 80 years make that date type column example retirement date column to null in pyspark? Can someone help me out for this

below table as you can see the date which is less 80 years it should be as it is but the date which is above 80 years should be null

Input data -

|retirement-date|
|24-08-1997|
|14-06-1929|

Expected Output -

|Retirement-date|
|24-08-1997|
|Null|

Comment: Have you tried anything thus far? Also please add your input and the expected output.

Comment: Yes actually I added a table as you can see above the the column contains 2 dates one date with 1997 and 1920 I want to make only that date 1920 to null because it's more then 80 years completed

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with case/when and few date functions, you can check my example. I added it as sql because of apache-spark-sql tag, it can be done ofc with Scala/Python

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

spark.conf.set("spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy", "EXCEPTION")

val inputData = Seq(
  "1997-08-24",
  "1929-06-14"
)

val inputDf = inputData.toDF("Retirement_date")
inputDf.createOrReplaceTempView("input")
spark
  .sql(
    "select CASE 1 WHEN DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE(), TO_DATE(Retirement_date, 'yyyy-MM-dd')) < DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE(), CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 80 YEARS) THEN Retirement_date ELSE Null END as Retirement_date from input"
  )
  .show()
```

Ouput is:

```
+---------------+
|Retirement_date|
+---------------+
|     1997-08-24|
|           null|
+---------------+
```

Comment: I actually did that in a similar way Thank you  but if retirement date is in dd-mm-yyyy  format means 24081997  then??

Comment: No yeah... it's date format retirement date is in this dd-mm-yyyy format